# Talend Open studio free version problem with Git

Tags: git, gitlab, talend

I'm currently worked on a talend job using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration the free version.
Pb : I cloned the repo from Gitlab, opend it in talend did some modifications and save it.
when I want to track modifications before pushed it into the repo with the command 'git status' nothing was tracked :

'On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean'

How can we track talend jobs modifications on an existed jobs cloned by git though  that every new job created by Talend itself on my local machine was succefully tracked by git

Answer (score 0):

We found that there are some things built into Talend Open Source that make Git, or even multiple developers a challenge. It is all related, so let me walk you through it.

First we use a single user profile for our Talend development. To do this we Shift+Right click on the program, and choose Run as user (Run as administrator causes massive corruption in the model, so don't do that). We have a service user just for Talend that we all use for this. Still only one user in a model at a time, but at least we can all use the same model.

Note: we tried having each user working within their own development environment, and just passing changes back and forth using Git. That failed miserably. The models were constantly being corrupted, and the diffs as a result of a single minor change were massive because anything opened was marked with the current user and an internal pointer that seemed to be generated for every session. Running Talend as a single user solved this issue, and by putting the Talend environment on a remote server that resides in the data center, we were able to share a Talend install among multiple developers, albeit with a single user at a time.

How does Git factor in to this now? We use Git to back up changes to the model. The process is Export from Talend to the working library, Commit, Push to the remote repository, which for us is on Bitbucket, however Gitlab should work as well. Clone the repository in a manner that will work for the exports (at least when using Windows) I had to use runas. Here's the program:

```
@if -%1-==-- echo Syntax error! & echo use TRUN "git command" & goto :OUT
runas /user:serviceUser /env /savecred %1
:OUT
```

This basically runs whatever I type after trun as our service user, and saves the credentials so we don't have to continuously log in to do it. Anything that could create libraries or files needs this trun command. So git clone, or git pull.

The "git clone" or "git pull" populates the working copy, but Talend does not have access to that directly. You need to import the model from the working copy in Talend first to get any changes. Fortunately as a result of everyone using the same installation of Talend for a given project, there is little reason to import as the changes are already there.

Git does add a little extra complexity though. The commit and push processes use our personal user id's instead of the service user, and as a result each developer must have their own local repository and working copy. If another user was the last one to make changes to the model with a commit an push, you must refresh your own local repository and working copy from the remote using "git pull" before exporting your changes and doing the commit and push.

It all seems like a lot of work, but once you get used to it, it isn't much more than normal development with git. You just have the extra Import/Export steps, and mostly just Export.

---

Just an FYI, Qlik (the new owner of Talend) is discontinuing the Open Source Talend at the end of January 2024 (within days now), but there is a effort afoot to clone the project and continue it apart from Qlik. I am hoping that the Git integration and multiuser issues with Talend can be solved by this group as they may be unhindered by the need to differentiate a high priced enterprise version of the product.